# c++ mpi derived datatypes on different machines

Tags: c++, mpi, cluster-computing

I want create a derived datatype. In particular I want a struct like this:

```
struct {
    int provider;
    double service;
    double cost;
} MPI_Struct;
```

Following a web manual, I should write something like that:

```
  int blocks[3] = {1,1,1};
  MPI_Datatype types[3] ={MPI_INT,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_DOUBLE};       
  MPI_Aint displacements[3];

  MPI_Datatype MPI_Struct;
  MPI_Aint doublex;

  MPI_Type_extent(MPI_DOUBLE,&doublex);

  displacements[0]=static_cast<MPI_Aint>(0);
  displacements[1]=doublex;
  displacements[2]=doublex+doublex;

  MPI_Type_struct(3,blocks,displacements,types,&MPI_Struct)
```

My matter is the use of `MPI_Type_extent` that it should be similar to `size_of()` function. Since my program will run on a cluster with different machines, with `MPI_Datatype_exent`, can I be sure that there are no problems in passing `My_Struct` from one process to another on a different machine?

If I'm not wrong, the types are not standard in bit length..

Comment: To what extend are your machines different?

Comment: In this moment i don t know the exact difference. They are university computer and i didn t use them yet.

Comment: Everything should be absolutely homogeneous. Do not run MPI on a mix of different OS / installations / versions / MPI implementations / compiler options / binaries / CPUs unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would write this

```
typedef struct {
    int provider;
    double service;
    double cost;
} mystruct;

displacements[0]=static_cast<MPI_Aint>(offsetof(mystruct, provider));
displacements[1]=static_cast<MPI_Aint>(offsetof(mystruct, service));
displacements[2]=static_cast<MPI_Aint>(offsetof(mystruct, cost));
MPI_Type_struct(3,blocks,displacements,types,&tmp_ddt);
MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_ddt, static_cast<MPI_Aint>(0), static_cast<MPI_Aint>(sizeof(mystruct)), &MPI_Struct);
MPI_Type_free(&tmp_ddt);
```

I am pretty sure `MPI_INT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are standard in bit length (fwiw,  Fortran `MPI_INTEGER` datatype is not), but the padding the compiler might use (or not) is not. that is why i'd rather use the `offsetof()` macro to populate the `displacements` array, and then resize the datatype.

Comment: thanks! What does MPI_create_resized do exactly? I'm new in mpi and especially with derived type.

Comment: `MPI_Type_create_resized()` basically set the extent. If you `MPI_Send()` two elements, the first one start at offset `0`, and the second one starts at offset `extent`. There is no guarantee MPI and the compiler will handle padding (if any) at the end of a struct, so it is safer to explicitly tell MPI what the compiler chose.